# kvm, vlans, how to simulate a 'mirror' port

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vlan

I'm working with kvm 0.14.1 on an ubuntu lucid x64 box.  I've got 3 vlans configured, one that is a bridge to the host's eth1.  The others are host only.

I want to start playing with snort.  Is there a way to configure a 'mirror' port into/onto one of the vlans from/to a kvm virtual machine ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand what you're after, then all you need to do is build a bridge on the vlan you want to listen to, and add a NIC to the VM, that will be plugged into that bridge.
The reason is simple - bridged interfaces are set in promiscous mode, and should be forwarding all bcast traffic to the VM.

Comment: hm...considered this but I don't think that will exactly do what I want.  I'm basically trying to replicate Cisco's SPAN (aka port mirroring).

Comment: that said, I'm thinking something like openvswitch may be an easy way to go.